# passing parameters to anonymous function with javascript .call()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am creating a basic queue method to iterate through an array of functions once a callback has completed.  This works fine but I am not able to pass any arguments, here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
var queue = {};
queue.type1 = [];

queue.type1.push(function(obj) { console.log('queued function called after callback', obj); });

var renderQueue = function(type, obj) {
    switch(type) {
        case 'type1':

            for(var i=0; i<queue[type].length; i++) {
             queue[type][i].call(obj);  
            }

            break;
        default:
            //
            break;

    }
}

var somecallback = function() {
    renderQueue('type1', { 'test': 'test' });   
}
somecallback();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bk5670e5/

Comment: what do you mean you not able to pass paramers? Of course you can pass parameters - read the spec - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: The syntax for [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is `fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`, It looks like you're missing the `thisArg`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this:

```
queue[type][i].call(obj);
```

Should just be this:

```
queue[type][i](obj);
```

When you use #call the first argument is the "this" context. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 0):

You can retain scope variables using an immediate invoked functions:

```
    var queue = {};
queue.type1 = [];

var renderQueue = function(type, obj) {
    console.log('type: '+ type)
    switch(type) {
        case 'type1':

            break;
        default:
            //
            break;

    }
}

var somecallback = function(type,obj) {
    return (function(t,o){renderQueue(t,o)}(type,obj));
}

queue.type1.push(somecallback('type1', { 'test': 'test' }))

queue.type1.push(somecallback('type2', { 'test': 'test' }))

for(var idx= 0;idx < queue.type1.length;idx++){
    queue.type1[idx];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.call(this, param1, param2, etc);
```